# Get the missing columns from one dataframe and append it to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe `df1` with the columns. I need to compare the headers of columns in `df1` with a list of headers from `df2`

```
df1 =['a','b','c','d','f']
df2 =['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

I need to compare the `df1` with `df2` and if any missing columns, I need to add them to `df1` with blank values.

I tried `concat` and also `append` and both didn't work. with `concat`, I'm not able to add the column `e` and with `append`, it is appending all the columns from `df1` and `df2`. How would I get only missing column added to `df1` in the same order?

```
df1_cols = df1.columns
df2_cols = df2._combine_match_columns

if (df1_cols == df2_cols).all():
        df1.to_csv(path + file_name, sep='|')
else:
    print("something is missing, continuing")
    #pd.concat([my_df,flat_data_frame], ignore_index=False, sort=False)
    all_list = my_df.append(flat_data_frame, ignore_index=False, sort=False)
```

I wanted to see the results as

```
a|b|c|d|e|f - > headers
1|2|3|4||5 -> values
```

Answer (score 3):

#### `pandas.DataFrame.align`

```
df1.align(df2, axis=1)[0]
```

- By default this does an `'outer'` join
- By specifying `axis=1` we focus on columns
- This returns a `tuple` of both an aligned `df1` and `df2` with the calling dataframe being the first element.  So I grab the first element with `[0]`

---

#### `pandas.DataFrame.reindex`

```
df1.reindex(columns=df1.columns | df2.columns)
```

- You can treat `pandas.Index` objects like sets most of the time.  So `df1.columns | df2.columns` is the union of those two index objects.  I then `reindex` using the result.

Answer (score 0):

Lets first create the two dataframes as:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)), columns = ['a','b','c','d','f'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,7)), columns = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'])
```

Now add those columns of df2 to df1 (with nan values), which are not in df1:

```
for i in list(df2):
    if i not in list(df1):
        df1[i] = np.nan
```

Now display the columns of df1 alphabetically:

```
df1 = df1[sorted(list(df1))]
```